# If I need to populate HTML elements, where should I do it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I have a `select` field on an html page. This can be in a Jinja2 template with Flask (what I happen to be using) or whatever template you want.

If I need to dynamically populate this select based on external data, in my case a database, how should I do it?

As I see it, I have three options:

1. Load the page and populate everything through ajax calls. Calling some script on the back end, getting the data, and returning it. The javascript would then handle actually creating the html to put into the select.
2. Generate the html on the back end before the page even loads and then insert it with a variable. This seems more straight-forward than #1, since the "flow" doesn't have to go back and forth between the front- and back-end.
3. A hybrid of #1 and #2 where I would get the data on the back end before the page loads. Then pass it off to the front end, using javascript to generate the html.

Writing these out finally, I would probably go with number 3, but since I have not had any formal training or guidance on this sort of stuff, I wouldn't know exactly what is *best*.

Additionally, is there a fourth or even fifth option? I am learning so I am open to anything.

Comment: if you have a template, pass the list of items to your template, iterate on it, create select options. options 1 and 3 don't need templates (or JS templates, such as backbone) and can use plain HTML.

Comment: Is the `select` going to be changing throughout the life cycle of the page? Or just for display? If you're going to be changing/saving the values of the `select` later you might as well use ajax so you can have some nice little functions that handle both *loading* and *saving* actions and you can just call them whenever needed (in your event handlers)

Comment: Isn't this more suited @ [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/#)?

Comment: @TilwinJoy Maybe. I am not sure. Reading the tiny paragraph on the front page makes it seem so maybe.